# groovy sed error sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Tags: groovy, sed

Groovy code is :

```
def cmd = "sed -i \'1 i <?xml version=\"1.1\"?>\' test.xml"
println cmd
println cmd.execute().err.text
```

Output:

```
sed -i '1 i <?xml version="1.1"?>' test.xml
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Here is the actual command `sed -i '1 i <?xml version="1.1"?>' test.xml` that runs well in cli. But Groovy `execute()` does not work correctly. How to fix this ?

**Update 1 :**

Also tried with the below `cmd`, butstill shows same error.

```
def cmd = /sed -i '1 i <?xml version="1.1"?>' test.xml/
def cmd = "sed -i '1 i <?xml version=\"1.1\"?>' test.xml"
```

**Update Note:**

To check and update an xml file,

```
def insertversion(String filename)
{
    def lines= new File (filename).readLines()
    if(!(lines.get(0)).contains('xml version'))
    {
        def cmd = ['sed', '-i', '1 i <?xml version="1.1"?>', filename]
        cmd.execute()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case execute shell command as a list of cmd and parameters instead of a executing command as String:

```
def cmd = ['sed', '-i', '1 i <?xml version="1.1"?>', 'test.xml']
println cmd
println cmd.execute().err.text
```

After running script like this part `<?xml version="1.1">` gets duplicated in `test.xml` file (same behavior as running given command from command line).

#### What is the difference between `List.execute()` and `String.execute()`?

If you execute shell command as a String, `java.lang.Runtime.exec()` method will use `java.util.StringTokenizer` to split your input String into an array. In your case tokenizer will create 7 tokens, you can check it by running following script:

```
def cmd = "sed -i \'1 i <?xml version=\"1.1\"?>\' test.xml"

def tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(cmd)
def tokens = []
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tokens << tokenizer.nextToken()
}

tokens.each { println it }
```

It outputs:

```
sed
-i
'1
i
<?xml
version="1.1"?>'
test.xml
```

You can also verify it by running debugger with a checkpoint set in `java.lang.Runtime` class at line 96:

[image]

This is of course incorrect. When using a list to execute shell command we will get correct array of command line parameters:

[image]

The general rule of thumb is that if your shell command contains characters that may confuse `java.util.StringTokenizer` it's better to use a list to define correct list of command line parameters.

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi Added an explanation what happens in both cases in your script. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Learned.. Thanks for your explanation :) really helps a lot.

Comment: My rule of thumb is: never use the string version